# Why can the new operator be with an initial value?

Tags: c++

As we know that the new operator can be used in the following way:
    int *a = new int(10);
and it means there is an int that the pointer named a points with a initial value which equals 10. But in http://www.cplusplus.com , I couldn't find such direction and I just want to know why the new operator can be used with a initial value? Is it similar with the constructor calling?

Comment: Nothing to do with `new`, it's just direct initialization of an integer variable. E.g. `int a(10);` declares an `int` called `a`  and initializes its value to `10`.

Comment: See [**direct-initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) on, imho, a considerably more informative language site.

Comment: I second cppreference being more informative most of the time. Also here's the relevant page for [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). It got a nice syntax section on the top and then all the details you'd ever wish for...

Answer (score 1):

> why the new operator can be used with a initial value?

The initial value (10) goes into the object (int) to which *a points.

> Is it similar with the constructor calling?

Yes.

---

Also works for auto vars

```
 int  B (20);
```

B is initialized to 20.